# Triggering basic event in other process

Tags: wpf, vb.net, process, ipc

I need a simple system that allows one process to check if another process is running (I think I can do that fine using Process.getProcessByName or similar) and then trigger an event in that process assuming it is.

When I say trigger an event I do not mean that literally. I simply need to trigger a sub in the first process from the second.

I know that IPC like this would normally be done with pipes or remoting or something like that but I have no experience with these and am looking for a quick solution, so unless these can be used relatively easily to solve this I am looking for an alternative.

If this is not clear in any way then I will add detail.

**EDIT:** Both processes will be running on the same machine.

Thanks for your help,

Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET the best idea is to use WCF. WCF is not only for web services, but for communication between any processes whether those are on the same or different machines. If you have any experiences in WCF services, this is the quickest solution. Here is a tutorial which describes the method:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Sorry I don't write any example I'm writing this on phone. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple way using a wait handle.  It could be simpler if you removed all of the cancellation code, which isn't strictly necessary if you don't need to cancel the HandleMessage thread.

Application 1 (the signalling app)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = 
        new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, 
            "3bee6ac3-2b48-4515-82f5-4fee255a674e");

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _waitHandle.Set();
    }
}
```

Application 2 (the signalled app)

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private readonly EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = 
        new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, 
        "3bee6ac3-2b48-4515-82f5-4fee255a674e"); // a unique name
    private readonly CancellationToken _token;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _token = _tokenSource.Token;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(HandleMessage, _token);
    }

    private void HandleMessage()
    {
        while(!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // wait for signal - but only for 1 second
            // so we can check for cancellation
            if (_waitHandle.WaitOne(1000))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Message received");
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled");
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // stop receiving
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this if the system in the previous answer does not work out. However I have implemented that already and it seems to work great, although I have only tested is briefly.